# Can I redownload a game I bought on the new 3ds if I bought it without a NNID?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id

Basically I'm planning on buying the new 3ds and I'm planning on transferring all the games from my older 3ds XL to it. But before I do that if I were to get on my new 3ds without setting a [NNID](http://www.nintendo.com/3ds/nintendo-network-id/) and I buy a game on the eshop without a NNID then transfer my old 3ds data to the new one would I lose access to the game I bought without a NNID on the new one?

Comment: Purchases are bound to the console, not the account. The 3DS didn't have NNID support originally but things may have changed in the meantime.

Comment: Do the transfer first, then buy anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you use system transfer, you shouldn't lose anything, because it transfers **all data** (except some technical stuff) to the new system **including** eShop data, and **anything on the new system** ***will*** **be lost.**

Comment: Indeed. Don't buy anything on your new 3DS without transfering data from the older system first.